# TIP127 + TL074 power supply doesn't work until I touch it

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, analog, feedback, pnp

I have such a schematic based on the TL074 opamp and the TIP127 PNP darlington transistor to control the fan voltage (shown as motor near the D3 diode). VCC = 12V, VDIG = 5V generated by a LM7805. The problem is that this schematic works perfectly in the simulation, yet it resists to work on the breadboard until I touch the opamp's positive input. After that, the schematic works perfectly until I try to turn it off and on again - it turns off fluently (using the pot), yet it does not turn on until I touch that positive input.

I don't understand what is going on. My guess is that I should put a capacitor somewhere, but I don't understand where and - more imporantly - why to make it work.

I am using a 12V 0.3A fan as a load.

[image]

Comment: As a quick and dirty guess, the circuit might be oscillating and touching it kills the osci.  Seen it before.  Scoping the osc would help find where to put a feww thousand pF.  When I was young an old timer told me to always have a scope in parallel with my meter and this has worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my thoughts: -

- The TL074 has a common mode input range that **does not** include the negative rail (0 volts on your circuit) so, when you power it up the non-inverting input is breaking the rules and the op-amp cannot be expected to function correctly. Typically, anything between 0 V and 3 volt on the input will likely cause problems.
- The TL074 has an output swing that does not reach the power rails so it's very unlikely that Q1 will switch off once it is on. This is probably what is mentioned in the question "until I try to turn it off".
- Adding an extra level of voltage gain to an op-amp is usually a recipe for disaster (it turns into an oscillator) if not done carefully. Q1 is a common emitter hence it has plenty of voltage gain from base to collector. In this circuit, that gain could be in the realm of about 50 to the junction of R2 and R3. If you look at figure 9 in the TL074 data sheet you will see that increasing gain by ten is probably enough to make the phase margin zero (it becomes an oscillator).

Problems all round really.

Answer (score 0):

Your supply is likely oscillating. Collector output has its disadvantages.

Also, for really lot output, you will need a r2r opamp. Or you cannot turn the PNP off, or not able to control at the low end of the output.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually came up with an another, temporary solution. The right solution is to use an another opamp with near R2R operation (like LM324) and use a schematic with a negative feedback.

The problem wasn't in the oscillation (that's very strange - the schematic **should** oscillate because of the positive feedback), instead it was in the opamp. The TL074 opamp, as some people have already mentioned in other anwsers, cannot handle the low-input cases. When the schematic is off (potentiometer is at the lowest setting), the voltage on the positive input of the TL074 opamp is 0V exactly. I tried after that turning on the motor by increasing the potentiometer value and therefore the TL074 opamp wasn't working in right conditions and failed to turn on the fan.

The solution I came up with is just to increase the voltage on the positive input of TL074 by adding a 100k resistor from the positive input to the VCC. Therefore, when the motor is turned off, a small current will still flow across 100k resistor R4 and R2, making a "shift" - a small voltage of around 1V at the positive input of TL074.

In this schematic, however, the motor voltage cannot reach values larger than 10.5V approx. because of the same "shift". The solution for this problem I came up to is to use a diode like it is shown on the second picture. I also added two diodes in series to higher up the voltage at the base of Q1 (which is also a very, very dirty solution).

Again, this is a temporary solution which should never be used. Thanks everybody for their anwsers and pointing out the actual problem which I solved with the described hack. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: The feedback is negative for the composite circuit, as the opamps output is reversed by the PNP.

Comment: The opamps cannot shut down the PNP. So the problems you were observing, of its inability to start, were not consistent with that problem.

Comment: @dannyf Nope, the schematic works even without these two diodes in series perfectly. They are just "to be sure"