# TL072CN op-amp question

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator

I'm a complete beginner in circuitry, I have a simple circuit, try to make the square oscillator.

9V, DC voltage, through op-amp

[image: a busy cat]

this circuit doesn't work until i touch positive wire amplifiers.
While holding the wire, it works, when I release it stops working
I found a similar problem in [this topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/285877/tip127-tl074-power-supply-doesnt-work-until-i-touch-it)

I also use TL072CN op-amp. I do not have a much experience to make a hack like on this topic, can someone give a hint what I need to do to make the circuit work?
I totally don't understand, why in simulation this works but on breadboard, this works only if I'm holding wire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimum recommended supply voltage for the TL072 opamp is 10 volts. You are running at 9 volts. You have also got your positive feedback incorrectly connected. This can be remedied by a 100 kohm resistor from non inverting input to positive rail. You can't just ignore the fact that the hysteresis needs to be built around a voltage that is halfway between power rails.

I can't say why your sim didn't show this problem but, looking at the circuit picture, it's likely that it is some really crappy free sim. Try a good free sim like LTSpice.

Try using a more suitable opamp next time.

Comment: Thank you, I racked my brains all day. How do you calculate it?  Is the sum of the min VCC+ and VCC- voltage modules for all op amps right?

Comment: You just need to ensure the average voltage at that input is somewhere central between the two power rails.